# Running functions based on user input in Rust

Tags: rust, match

I'm new to the Rust language and as I usually do when trying to pick up a language, I like to go through Euler Project questions. I want to get familiar with cargo and everything it offers, so I've created a cargo project called euler-project.

On startup, I want the program to ask the user which solution to run and have it run a function in the code that corresponds to the solution requested by the user.

I like to avoid huge chains of if / else if / else blocks, so I thought the match function would work well. Here's what I have.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    
    // Solution selection. Every solution will be selectable here
    let mut selection = String::new();

    // Enum to hold every solved problem number for match control flow
    enum Solutions {
        P1, P2, 
    }

    loop {
        println!("Select the solution you would like to run. (Example: '32' would be Problem 32)");

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut selection)
            .expect("Input should be an integer.");
        
        
        match selection {
            Solutions::P1 => p1(),
            Solutions::P2 => p2(),
        }
    }
}

fn p1() {
    println!("p1")
    
}

fn p2() {

}
```

Currently this produces an error as follows:

```
...
21 |         match selection {
   |               --------- this expression has type `std::string::String`
22 |             Solutions::P1 => p1(),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found enum `main::Solutions`
```

What am I doing wrong here? If you know a better option for doing this type of control, please suggest it to me. I am also curious to know if there is anything similar to Python's interactive console mode that allows a user to run the code in the terminal, and to make function calls by simply typing function names and hitting enter.

Comment: You are matching a `String` to an enum. The system has no way of knowing if a `String` value is the enumerated option. You would need to either match the `String` value or the integer value. I'm not sure why you have the enum at all. Enums do not evaluate to integer values.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6ddecdfa321e58440c04183dfe5b3166 but on euler case I would probably advice a array at some point there is like +300 exercise :p.

Comment: Probably an overkill for now, but `clap` is a great library to help parse command line arguments: https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges here. On the one hand, you have the string you have read from the user, and on the other hand you have values of type `Solutions`, but nowhere do you tell the compiler how to compare the two. The easiest way to do what you want is just to compare strings directly:

```
match selection.trim() {
    "1" => p1(),
    "2" => p2(),
    _ => panic!("{} does not designate a valid problem!", selection),
}
```

Note the call to `trim`: the string returned by `read_line` includes the trailing newline, which you need to remove so that the comparisons will work.

Note also that you will need to call `selection.clear()` before `read_line`, otherwise the next iteration of the loop will *append* to the string instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't match an enum with a String. You could try something like:

```
match selection.trim().parse::<i32>() {
    Ok(x) if x == (Solutions::P1 as i32) => p1(),
    Ok(x) if x == (Solutions::P2 as i32)=> p2(),
    x => panic!{x},
}
```